Building Python Packages from Source for AMD GPU - hipcc failed with exit code 127 --rocm-path not found
I am trying to install Python packages, like lietorch or pytorch-scatter with AMD support.
I download the repository,
git clone --recursive https://github.com/repo

If I just try to install the package, I'll get an error, stating

clang: error: cannot find HIP runtime; provide its path via '--rocm-path', or pass '-nogpuinc' to build without HIP runtime

Therefore, I change the extra_compile_args inside setup.py, adding
'-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=--rocm-path=/opt/rocm'

to the nvcc flags.
The flags get passed and is executed by hipcc:
/opt/rocm-6.0.2/bin/hipcc _various_compile_flags_ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=--rocm-path=/opt/rocm-6.0.2 _even_more_flags_

But it terminates with the error
sh: 1: --rocm-path=/opt/rocm-6.0.2/llvm/bin/clang: not found
sh: 1: --rocm-path=/opt/rocm-6.0.2/llvm/bin/clang: not found
error: command '/opt/rocm-6.0.2/bin/hipcc' failed with exit code 127

Is there anything I can do to get the packages built? Do these packages have insufficient support for AMD and there is nothing I can do? Or is there a grave oversight on my part and an obvious solution?
Some System Information:
GPU:
AMD Radeon RX 6800 XT (gfx1030)

Environment Variables:
ROCM_PATH=/opt/rocm
ROCM_ROOT=/opt/rocm
ROCM_HOME=/opt/rocm-6.0.2
CPATH=/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/hip:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/rocrand:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/hiprand:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/roctracer:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/hipblas:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/hipsparse:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/hipfft:/opt/rocm-6.0.2/include/rocsolver
HIP_PATH=/opt/rocm/hip
HCC_HOME=/opt/rocm/hcc
HIP_PLATFORM="amd"
PYTORCH_ROCM_ARCH="gfx1030"
HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION=10.3.0
HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0

I tried setting the rocm-path flag as described above and looked for help in github issues and Stack Overflow posts without success.
I expect the packages to compile successfully and run on my hardware.

While searching for an answer I stumbled upon this Clang documentation.
It mentions the Order of Precedence for HIP Path:

Order of Precedence for HIP Path

--hip-path compiler option

HIP_PATH environment variable (use with caution)

--rocm-path compiler option

ROCM_PATH environment variable (use with caution)

Default automatic detection (relative to Clang or at the default ROCm installation location)



Including --hip-path=/opt/rocm inside the extra_compile_args let me compile the packages.

As a side note: while pytorch-scatter compiled without problems, lietorch still has issues with the conversion from CUDA to HIP code and does not run. But this seems secondary to the main question and a problem with lietorch's support for AMD.
